# Connecting to Google Drive with WebDAV

Tags: google-drive, webdav

Have anyone managed to connect to Google Drive with WebDAV?

I have tried with:
Remote URL: `drive.google.com`
and using my google email and password, but failing to connect.

Does Google support WebDAV at all? Did not manage to find any good answer.